# perl - open file - getting date

Tags: perl

Is there a more efficient way of getting the date in perl, and I have seen the open statement formatted differently - is this the acceptable way of opening the file ?

```
06:27:54 /data/noc/startup/startup_ptf_pats.sh startup initiated by waljoh @ Tue Nov  1      06:27:54 EDT 2011
06:27:54 /data/noc/startup/startup_ptf_pats.sh verifying that engine is change controlled
06:27:54 /data/noc/startup/check_change_controlled_files.sh all change controlled commands files are in synch
06:27:54 /data/noc/startup/check_today_is_holiday.sh Today is NOT a holiday
06:27:54 /data/noc/startup/check_ntpq.sh 159.79.35.42 time offset (0) is below 100
```

This is the script  I wrote:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my $todays_date = `/bin/date +%m-%d-%y`;
chomp $todays_date ;

my $grabDIR = "/data/noc/startup/logs/";
my $grabFILE = "pats." . "$todays_date" . ".txt";

print "$grabDIR$grabFILE\n" ;

my FILE;
open (FILE, "more $grabDIR$grabFILE | ");
while (<FILE>) {
        my $line = $_;
        print $line; 
        sleep 1;
}
```

Comment: Erm, yeah. Don't do that. http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/localtime.html and ... you may want to also read how to actually open and read files.

Comment: Your code sample has a fatal error on the "my FILE" line.  You don't mean to localize a bare filehandle, I think.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As for the date:

```
use POSIX ();
my $todays_date = POSIX::strftime( '%m-%d-%Y', localtime );
```

Best practices for open are the 3-argument open -- and no need to `more` it.

```
open( my $fh, '<', "$grabDIR$grabFILE" ) 
    or die "Could not open $grabDIR$grabFILE! - $!"
    ;
```

Also note the use of a *lexical* file handle ( `$fh` ), also preferred today.

Answer (score 2):

Don't fork external commands (e.g. 'date' and 'more') to do things Perl can intrinsically do.  As already noted, you can use the POSIX module's strftime() to format the timestamp you obtain from your server's localtime.

For open() use the three-argument form for safely:

```
open (FILE, '<', $grabDIR$grabFILE) or die "Can't open $grabDIR$grabFILE: $!\n";
```

This opens for input and if an error occurs reports that (via '$!') and dies.  Rather than a bare-word file handle (e.g. FILE) use an autovivified one like this:

```
 open (my $fh, '<', $grabDIR$grabFILE) or die "Can't open $grabDIR$grabFILE: $!\n";
 while (<$fh>) {
     ...
```

See the perlopentut for more information: [perlopentut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlopentut.html)